# Split Hours into Multiple Months using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE EventLog 
(
  EventID INT
, EventName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, EventStartDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL
, EventEndDateTime   DATETIME NULL 
)


INSERT INTO EventLog(EventID, EventName, EventStartDateTime, EventEndDateTime)
VALUES(100, 'Planting', '20210620 10:34:09 AM','20211018 10:54:49 PM')
 ,(200, 'Foundation', '20200420 10:34:09 AM','20211018 10:54:49 PM')
 ,(300, 'Seeding', '20210410 10:27:19 AM','')
 ,(400, 'Spreading', '20220310 10:24:09 PM','')
```

I have a requirement to split hours into multiple months and even years depending on the length of the event. In some cases, the event may have an end date but if the event is still ongoing, there will be no end date.

The result or output of the solution is to be held by another table:

```
CREATE TABLE EventSummary
(  
  EventID INT
, EventName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, [Year] INT
, [MonthName] VARCHAR(25) 
, [Hours] DECIMAL(12,2) 
)
```

[image: Desired output]
The image above is the output of the first row.

If the event runs over multiple years, the values should be spread across the multiple years and months likewise.
In cases where there is no end date I am to use GETUTCDATE() to do the calculation.
Some events span across months or event years. I would like to be able to break down the total duration into individual month's duration  (or individual duration by month) in hours respectively and populate it into a table

Consider that I have an event with start and end date: '20210620 10:34:09 AM','20211018 10:54:49 PM'
For the first month which basically is not a full month, I am to calculate the remaining hours of that month and store it against that month.
I do the same for the next month. If the event runs for the entire month which is now the month of July, I store the entire hours for that month which is 744 hours against July. I keep doing that till the end of the event. But if the event is still open(blank or empty) I use
GETUTCDATE() as the end date
The sum of Hours is grouped by EventID, EventName, Year and Months
It is expected that the first and or last month may be decimals as they may not be fully formed.

I have tried to work this out but do not know how to get the best result with SQL Server.
I kindly will appreciate your help with this.
Thanks

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? Also the DDL for your expected results and the image of your expected result don't align.

Comment: What's your expected result? it might not match from your sample data?

Comment: My expected result is to explode the difference between start and end date time into hours by eventid, eventname, year and month.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, no. But I got what you mean. The image above is not my expected result but a guide as to the month and hour outlook.

Comment: @UpwardD What is your expected if the `EventEndDateTime` is an empty string?

Comment: If your expected results is the image, what does *"The result or output of the solution is to be held by another table:"* mean when it's followed by a table that has a definition that is *nothing like* your expected results.

Comment: Hi @D-Shih
For an empty EventEndDateTime use GETUTCDATE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use CTE recursive, get each month startdate then use antoher `cte2` get the starttime and endtime between each month.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT EventID,EventName,EventStartDateTime,IIF(EventEndDateTime = '',GETUTCDATE(),EventEndDateTime) EventEndDateTime
   FROM EventLog
   UNION ALL
   SELECT EventID,EventName, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , EventStartDateTime)), 0) , EventEndDateTime
   FROM CTE 
   WHERE  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , EventStartDateTime)), 0)  <= EventEndDateTime
), CTE2 AS (
   SELECT EventID,EventName,EventStartDateTime,LEAD(EventStartDateTime,1,EventEndDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY EventID,EventName ORDER BY EventStartDateTime) n_EventStartDateTime
   FROM CTE
)
INSERT INTO EventSummary(EventID,EventName,Year,MonthName,Hours)
SELECT EventID,EventName,YEAR(EventStartDateTime),DATENAME(MONTH,EventStartDateTime),DATEDIFF(second, EventStartDateTime, n_EventStartDateTime) / 3600.0
FROM CTE2
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4878c47c6f3e5c6e04b43caebe20956c)

Comment: @UpwardD Could you provide your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: Hello @D-Shih
Thanks for the effort. The solution is different from what I want.

Consider that I have these start and end date: '20210620 10:34:09 AM','20211018 10:54:49 PM'
For the first month which basically is not a full month, I am to calculate the remaining hours of that month and store it. I do the same for the next month. If the event runs for the entire month which is now the month of July, I store the entire hours for that month which is 744. I keep doing that till the end of the event but if the event is still open(blank or empty) I use 
GETUTCDATE() as end date

Comment: @UpwardD I saw you update your question but word might be hard to know your logic. could you provide text expect results for your sample data?

Comment: Hi D-Shih. I the image on the updated question is a reflection of what I want. Thank you

Comment: @UpwardD I had edited my answer you can try that! BTW I think the hour might be a little problem I use datediff to calculate hour in the end hours https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=511d56771435f26840b539646d4406a1

Comment: Wow @D-Shih, it seems interesting already. I think this might just be the answer that I need. Will review and get back soon

Comment: @UpwardD if you only allow one `CTE` we can try to use subquery https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4aade2a388ffa21356f1581c4212b540

Comment: Thank you @D-Shih. Sorry if my comment wasn't clear. It does not allow UNION using the same name of the same cte 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT EventID,EventName, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , EventStartDateTime)), 0) , EventEndDateTime
   FROM CTE - line 6 to 7 from the last query window. Grateful

Comment: The issue is FROM EventLog UNION .....from CTE with the same name